# Rewrite and replace url wp-admin/edit.php and wp-admin/post-new.php

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

everybody

I want to rewrite and replace all url

**mydomain.com/wp-admin/edit.php -> mydomain.com/wp-admin/edit/**

and

**mydomain.com/wp-admin/post-new.php -> mydomain.com/wp-admin/addnewpost/**

How i can do it or suggest ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Not possible without massive side-effects. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The **technical** answer to this is to put an `.htaccess` file inside your `wp-admin` folder with this code:

```
# Remove .php from pages so you can use /wp-admin/edit
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Use /wp-admin/addnewpost
RewriteRule addnewpost post-new.php
```

The **practical** answer is that this is completely horrible, involves making sure your Apache server parses `.htaccess` below root, and won't remove the extension from the links in admin so you'll still see `/wp-admin/post-new.php` when you click a link to create a new post.

Above all else, it breaks the way WordPress Admin is intended to be used, and is a BAD IDEA. Please don't do it.